# how to update empty value with bind parameters in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am creating message delete script in PHP MYSQLI. I have added zero value to update column. my script is working but I want to add zero value with bind parameters.

Here is my source code

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
if (isset($_GET['to_id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['to_id'];
    $session_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
}

$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE pm SET from_delete = '0' WHERE id = ? AND from_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",  $id, $session_id);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo"deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Failed to delete<br/>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add another placeholder `?` and bind value to it:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE pm SET from_delete = ? WHERE id = ? AND from_id = ?");
$zero = '0';
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $zero, $id, $session_id);
```

Comment: I added your script but showing like this message-Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\npm\delete.php on line 26

Comment: __Updated__ the code. I forgot that arguments should be passed by reference to `bind_param`.

Comment: Zero has also a value.